# Need help to make a tabsystem for this HTML

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm working on a school project. http://euctester.dk/htx153d/casperh/ep/

I would like to make a tabsystem on this page: http://euctester.dk/htx153d/casperh/ep/kravogregleruv%C3%A6rdi.html

I have tried som guides, but without any luck.

This is my HTML for the tabs. I can't seem to find out how to make some JavaScript, that will be able to change the class of the different divs.

```
<div id="selector">
    <div id="tabs1">
        <a  href="#tabs_content1"><div id="tabs1-1" class="active">
            <p>Generelt</p>
        </div></a>

        <a  href="#tabs_content2"><div id="tabs1-2" class="">
            <p>Nybyggeri</p>
        </div></a>

        <a  href="#tabs_content3"><div id="tabs1-3" class="">
            <p>Ændret anvendelse</p>
        </div></a>

        <a  href="#tabs_content4"><div id="tabs1-4" class="">
            <p>Energirenovering</p>
        </div></a>

        <a  href="#tabs_content5"><div  id="tabs1-5" class="">
            <p>Tilbygning</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="tabs_content1" class="tab active">
                <h1>Generelt</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs_content2" class="tab">
                <h1>Nybyggeri</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs_content3" class="tab">
                <h1>Ændret anvendelse</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs_content4" class="tab">
                <h1>Energirenovering</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
        </div>

        <div id="tabs_content5" class="tab">
                <h1>Tilbygning</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: HTML5 data attributes will help you. Bind the content to it's respective btn and display it when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution, i will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html code you can try add a class like `myTab` to tabs and for your div `content`, for example:

```
<div id="selector">
    <div id="tabs1">
        <div id="tabs1-1" class="myTab active">
            <p>Generelt</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs1-2" class="myTab">
            <p>Nybyggeri</p>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div id="tabs1-1_content" class="content" style="display: block;">
        <div id="tabs1-1_content1">
            <h1>Generelt</h1>
            <p>Your content 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs1-2_content" style="display: none;" class="content">
        <div id="tabs1-2_content2">
            <h1>Nybyggeri</h1>
            <p>Your content 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally using jQuery function like this:

```
$('.myTab').on('click', function(){ 
    $('.myTab').removeClass('active');
    $('.content').hide();
    var content = '#'+$(this).attr('id')+'_content';
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(content).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use bootstrap. Its very easy to use.(refer : [Bootstrap Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs) )

Following code will help you to display tabs using bootstrap. Here is link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwhjtke1/1/)

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Generelt</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Nybyggeri</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Ændret anvendelse</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Energirenovering</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Tilbygning</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h1>Generelt</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>Nybyggeri</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>Ændret anvendelse</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>Energirenovering</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab5" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h1>Tilbygning</h1>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
                <p> text text........... text.....</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With little code changes you can generate vertical tabs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i'm afraid i can't use bootstrap for this. I have to be able to account for every bit of coding at the exam, and my teacher told me that Bootstrap is out of the question. I will, though, use bootstrap if i'm ever going to make a website again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Tabs using css</title>
  <style>
    .tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 220px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
    .tab {
  float: left;
}
   .tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
  background-color: aqua;
} 
    .tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
    .content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    background: yellow;  
}
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: silver;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="tabs">
    
   <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
     <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
       
       <div class="content">
          Alan McNicoll (1908–1987) was a senior officer in the Royal Australian Navy (RAN) and a diplomat. He graduated from the Royal Australian Naval College in 1926. Attached to the Royal Navy in the Second World War.
       </div> 
   </div>
    
   <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
       
       <div class="content">
           The Normandy landings (codenamed Operation Neptune) were the landing operations on Tuesday, 6 June 1944 (termed D-Day) of the Allied invasion of Normandy in Operation Overlord during World War II. 
       </div> 
   </div>
    
    <div class="tab">
       <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
       <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
     
       <div class="content">
           Operation Bodyguard was the code name for a World War II deception plan employed by the Allied states before the 1944 invasion of north-west Europe.
       </div> 
   </div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a way u can make tabs, and toggle in between them, just by using css

Comment: Thanks. I just started coding, so my skills are basically limited to html and css, so i will try this before the .js or .jquery solutions, since i have to be able to account for my coding at the exam...

Comment: Welcome, you can give this as best answer or vote up, if u think this is satisfied answer. Happy Coding!